# html var pixelHeight resize to size of window or screen

Tags: javascript, html

So I have been having a lot of trouble with this program I am createing for my own personal use. I am having troupble getting the window to resize to the size of the screen. I do not know all that much about the file, as I am not the origonal creater but my freind made it. what I want to have is the screen resize to the size of the window that the html file is opened in. The only variable that seems to control the size is the line
var pixelHeight = 8;
with the next few lines being, although non of those seem to affect screen size of the object. what can be added to make Var pixelWidth variable to the size of the screen window, or even the size of the monitor, I have been trying for a few days know using google but every change I have made just breaks it so it no longer displays properly, or at all. I would like to make it so that pixelHeight = windowheight / 120 as it should make it work, but anything I have tried for variables on window height or screen height that I found of google dont work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var pixelWidth = 8;  
</script>
<!-- Icon Map -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="icons.js"></script>
<!-- Game Data -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="game.js"></script>
<!-- Game Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="LEK.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var drawHack = false;
    var GAP_X = 12;
    var GAP_Y = 22;
    var GRID_WIDTH = 159;
    var GRID_HEIGHT = 113;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use screen.width and screen.height

Exemple from https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FFH3OMES1YOE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Open a new window, and resize the width and height of the new window.</p>

<button onclick="openWin()">Create window</button>
<button onclick="resizeWinTo()">Resize the window</button>


<script>
var myWindow;

function openWin() {
    myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=250, height=250");
}

function resizeWinTo() {
    myWindow.resizeTo(screen.width,screen.height);
    myWindow.focus();
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can test this exemple clicking in the link.

Comment: If the link crashes, I'm not to blame. Hope this helps you.